# MySQL read/write ratio from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS

Tags: mysql

Could you please help me to construct a query to sum specific rows from a table, basically desired output is:

```
+-----------------+----------------+
| Total reads     | Total writes   |
+-----------------+----------------+
| 345436          | 345435         |
+-----------------+----------------+
```

- Total reads = Com_select
- Total writes = Com_delete, Com_insert, Com_update, Com_replace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the typical trick of `sum(IF` the column is the right one, use it, if not read 0:

```
SELECT sum(IF(variable_name = 'Com_select', variable_value, 0)) as `Total reads`,
       sum(IF(variable_name IN ('Com_delete', 'Com_insert', 'Com_update', 'Com_replace'),
           variable_value, 0)) as `Total writes` 
FROM information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS;
```